# In JSP setProperty useBean how do we populate Lists

Tags: jsp, usebean

My source code is:

```
public class ContestForm
{
    List<SubContestForm> subContests;
}
public class SubContestForm
{
    int minAgeInclusive;
}

<jsp:useBean id="cont" class="com.kids.forms.ContestForm" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="cont" property="*"/>
```

Now, what name should I give to my form element so that minAgeInclusive is automatically populated on ContestForm ?
I tried

```
subContests[0].minAgeInclusive
```

but this is not working !